# Unable to install oracledb@4.0.1

Tags: node.js, npm, node-oracledb

I have a nodejs project and when I run npm i I run into the following error:

```
oracledb ERR! NJS-067: a pre-built node-oracledb binary was not found for Node.js v12.13.0 (NODE_MODULE_VERSION=72) on darwin x64
oracledb ERR! Try compiling node-oracledb source code using https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#github
```

I have tried updating the package.json to include "oracledb": "github:oracle/node-oracledb#v4.0.1" but it continues to show oracledb@3.1.2 install. I tried running npm uninstall oracledb as well but also caused the same error.

NodeJs v: 12.13.0
Python: 2.7.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i downgraded NodeJs to version 8.x.x (or less than 12.x.x) as there is no pre-built node-oracledb binary for  Node.js v12.13.0. Then I ran npm i again and it worked.

Comment: You should upgrade to use node-oracledb 4. It was built and tested with Node.js 12.  And node-oracle calls Node.js's N-API layer so each node-oracledb binary can run with multiple major versions of Node.js.

Comment: after upgrading node-oracle 3 to 4, still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ES module, change the file .js to .mjs, and using require instead of import. It works for me, I think node-oracledb is ESM now.

Answer (score 0):

Hunt around for any node_modules/oracledb directory and remove it manually.  Node.js may look up and down the directory tree.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Let me give it a try.